# How to center input buttons inside a form html

Tags: html, css

I have multiple input buttons that live inside a form , the inputs are not center on the page.

currently it only displays one row of the input divs but i'd like it to fill the page width margin of around 20px on each side and also adjust to browser screen size, how can i do this ? appreciate your answers, Thanks!

```css
.main_buttons {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-select {
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #7a7979;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container main_buttons">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12">

      <form class="select_form" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}


        <div class="btn-select">
          <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="0"><span>sydney</span></input>
                            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-select">
          <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="1"><span>tokyo</span></input>
                            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-select">
          <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="2"><span>london</span></input>
                            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-select">
          <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="3"><span>new york</span></input>
                            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-select">
          <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="4"><span>paris</span></input>
                            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-select">
          <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="5"><span>madrid</span></input>
                            </label>
        </div>





        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary city_submit_button">SUBMIT</button>

      </form>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Note that `<input>` is an empty tag (replaced element). It has not closing tag! As such `</input>` is invalid.

Comment: ok, i'll remember that , but that doesn't change the view or function of the button either way

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use position property. I wrapped the label and input fields inner div container named wrapper. Then i add display:style to the label.

```css
.main_buttons {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  }

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
label {
  display:block;
}

.btn-select {
  margin:4px;
  background-color:#7a7979;
  border-radius:4px;
  overflow:auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container main_buttons">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12">

            <form class="select_form" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}                
                    <div class="btn-select wrapper">
                        <div class="inner">                          
                          <input class="" type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="0">
                          <label class=""><span>sydney</span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              
                    <div class="btn-select wrapper">
                        <div class="inner">                          
                          <input class="" type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="0">
                          <label class=""><span>tokyo</span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>              

                    <div class="btn-select wrapper">
                        <div class="inner">                          
                          <input class="" type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="0">
                          <label class=""><span>london</span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="btn-select wrapper">
                        <div class="inner">                          
                          <input class="" type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="0">
                          <label class=""><span>new york</span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-select wrapper">
                        <div class="inner">                          
                          <input class="" type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="0">
                          <label class=""><span>paris</span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn-select wrapper">
                        <div class="inner">                          
                          <input class="" type="checkbox" name="city_select" value="0">
                          <label class=""><span>madird</span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>               
          
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary city_submit_button">SUBMIT</button>
          
            </form>

        </div>
            
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: thanks but doesn't work for me ,  with this solution the checkbox is visible and scroll bars also

Comment: @milo2810 in your question you dont speak about scroll bar and unvisble checkoxes?

Comment: no , the button is supposed to be like this : http://jsfiddle.net/Vq759/1/  but with the solution you provided i'm getting a scroll bar on side and bottom of button